# A object contain the two arrays. how I match the id from all arrays?

Tags: mongodb

I have the object contain two arrays of how I match the id from these two arrays using or condition.

e.g

```
    {
stauts:"matched",
members:{
groupA:[{
    "userName" : "Malik",
    "firstName" : "Adil",
    "_id" : "5f3d05ceb1268c1cc208ef90",
}],
groupB:[{
    "userName" : "Simi",
    "firstName" : "Doe",
    "_id" : "5f37b790b9c01886b29238fc",
},{
    "userName" : "GK",
    "firstName" : "gk",
    "_id" : "5f3d05ceb1268c1cc208ef90",
 }]
}
}
```

I have an id of one member and want to fetch the detail of the record.

Comment: can you explain more and can yiu share what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` to filter using `_id`.

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      groupA: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$members.groupA",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this._id",
              "5f3d05ceb1268c1cc208ef90"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      groupB: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$members.groupB",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this._id",
              "5f3d05ceb1268c1cc208ef90"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fg4BOmYb1FN)

Comment: it gives all the data but I need only those data in which id exit in group A or group B. with all other info e.g status

Comment: I have removed "5f37b790b9c01886b29238fc" details form groupB. Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/J96tgucE60a help you?